Creating a command to enable specific set of extensions
I've found myself in a state, where I work on projects in different languages, requiring different sets of extensions enabled.
I've tried enabling them manually per workspace, but this is getting tedious when you are opening a new workspace every hour.
I've tried profiles, but it's not really a solution. I don't have two different brains, and keeping track of all settings and keyboard shortcut changes between profiles is not what I'm looking for in the future.
I want a set of commands which would "enable extensions suitable for PHP development", "enable extensions suitable for POSIX shell development", "… for PowerShell", "… for Pascal", "… for Java", and other JavaScript stuff.
Is this possible inside VS Code or am I looking for some command-line foo as the last resort? Which, given #66750, is… undesirable.

Related: Can I configure specific VSCode extensions to only be enabled based on the current language?

"keeping track of all settings and keyboard shortcut changes between profiles is not what I'm looking for in the future" if this is the only issue you have with profiles... you know profiles can inherit from the default profile, right?

do you create a new project/workspace every hour, or you type very fast and without errors or they are all very small and all files can be put in one workspace and use variables in the task to designate the current file, all my python experiments are in one workspace, all my VSC extension developments are in one Multi Root workspace

Yes, I do create new project every hour. I'm learning a new language and doing lessons as I go. No, I don't want to use profiles. They COPY default profile, but they WON'T STAY IN SYNC with default profile. As I said, I don't have two separate heads to use two separate profiles. Or three. Or… you understand.

@wjandrea I specifically mentioned that I'm aware of this feature, but for a given application, it's tedious. I create new workspaces regularly. Be it a next lesson, or a next project cloned from GitHub, this is just too tedious to keep track of all relevant extensions.

@AnrDaemon I know you're aware of profiles. The question I linked to isn't about profiles, that's just the top answer.

As far as I know, at the time of this writing, the exact thing you're asking for is not possible. Now, if there was a pair of commands to enable or disable a set of extensions by ID, then this would be possible. Even if the command were only to enable/disable a single command, you could use runCommands. See also How do I add a keyboard shortcut to activate/disable a VSCode extension?.
I personally suggest looking into using profiles to solve this. If you want examples, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_profile-templates. If you have concerns about repetition between profiles, my understanding is that that's what Partial Profiles are for.
